# Factory - field with sequence as fallback

Tags: ruby, rspec2, factory-bot

**Question:** How can i use for one field both sequence and transient attribute?

**Background:** I have factory, which has a name. The name is sequence to keep it unique. However in few specs i need it set name chosen by me so i can predict it in expectation. It's not a Rails project.

In my head it looks like `name {attribute_from_create_call||FactoryGirl.generate :name}`. But i don't know how to get the attribute which i give to the create method

Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :name do |n|
    'Testing Bridge '+n.to_s
  end

  factory :historical_bridge do
    name {FactoryGirl.generate :name}
  end
end
```

Usage of factory: `FactoryGirl.create :historical_bridge, name: 'Bridge from '+Time.now.to_s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FactoryGirl to create a hash of attributes with the sequences and then merge in whatever changes to that hash you want:

```
new_name = 'Bridge from '+Time.now.to_s
attr = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:historical_bridge).merge(:name => new_name)
```

And then you could do something perhaps like create an object with those custom attributes:

```
HistoricalBridge.create(attr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use predefined name instead of sequence but check something like:

```
let(:bridge) { create :historical_bridge }

it { HistoricalBridge.something.name.should == bridge.name }
```

Comment: Finally, factory_girl is not the best approach for fast specs, but it is out of current scope. ;)